# divding resources among processes - sites get's slow during heavy uploading of csv files to sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, server, hosting, database-performance

I understand that's not a very specific question, but still asking in hope as it's something I don't have much knowledge of.

We have .net desktop application which runs as schedules service daily on the server uploads about 80M records from csv files. then afcourse we have lot of algorithms going on the data after the uploading. this whole process takes around 7 hrs.

As a server setup we have a dedicated window server with sql server 2008 R2. So we have our site and our application ( data uploading) running there. **But when application is running our site becomes slower and sometimes un-responsive** I totally understand the reason. but don't know the way out.

Just to be more clear, we have two databases. while the uploading is going on site is using the second database.. After uploading databases are switched so application use the latest data.

In my mind I can think of following.. Just thoughts, I don't even know if possible.

1. Perhaps there can be like two machines. one for data uploading and one for serving sites. but somehow both can use the same sql server. I hope with this sort of structure, resources being used by the desktop application wouldn't slow down the site as that has it's own resources to use

2.) Perhaps I can limit the cpu/memory that can be used by the application.

Note: few of the queries get's very complicated and runs long. sometimes upto 30 minutes.
Using IIS as web server.

Comment: I would definitely go with a two-machine solution.   Three-machine would be even better.   Having your SQL Server on the same physical box as your web server is far from optimal.

Comment: @TabAlleman I would like to know more about this if you can. How that works. is having sql server on different machine would slow down the data upload process? it's already 7 hours.

Comment: what edition are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to address your 2 points one by one:

**The 2 machines option**

That could be a viable solution but you would need to keep in mind that you need an extra windows and an extra SQL Server license + maybe additional hardware, I'm not sure if that's the most cost effective option;

**Limiting resources**

That is also a possibility if you have SQL Server enterprise edition, look into [Resource Governor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx) for more information on how to set that up.

> SQL Server Resource Governor is a feature than you can use to manage
>   SQL Server workload and system resource consumption. Resource Governor
>   enables you to specify limits on the amount of CPU, physical IO, and
>   memory that incoming application requests can use.

If you don't have Enterprise edition that is not an option.

There might be a third option which is available with standard edition too.

**Multiple instances**

You could install 2 instances of SQL on the same box and assign them different memory limits.

If IO is your bottleneck you could also opt for different data/log drives for each instance.

Comment: we have standard edition. I don't understand why on first option we will need to two license? My desktop application and web site are using the same database so shouldn't I'll keep them in one sql server instance? Infact I was thinking we'll have sql server only on one machine (with data uploading application) and website on another. Assuming connecting to sql server on different machine wouldn't slow down the site a lot..

Comment: in your question you explicitly state "Just to be more clear, we have two databases. while the uploading is going on site is using the second database"